# How can i add label to apex:selectOptions?

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectoption

I'm trying to add a label to `apex:selectOptions`, but cant figure out how to display it, I'v managed to add it in the object but cant display in VFP 
,any help?

**EDIT:**
thanks for your answers, but let me fix my question,
I meant how can i add vars to an option, for example i need another data to attach to the option, how can i do that?

```
public class AvailableCandidates{ 
 String[] farmsList = new String[]{};

     public List<SelectOption> getItems(){
         List<SelectOption> accounts = new List <SelectOption>();
         for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name,ParentId FROM Account]){

           SelectOption option =   new SelectOption(a.Id,a.Name);
             if(a.ParentId != null)
             option.setLabel(a.ParentId);

             accounts.add(option);
         }
         return accounts;
     }

  public String[] getFarmsList(){
    return farmsList;
  }

  public void setFarmsList(String[] farmsList) {
        this.farmsList = farmsList;
  }
}


<apex:form>
   <apex:selectList value="{!farmsList}" multiselect="false" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
   </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the value in `SelectOption` list you can set the label.

```
SelectOption option = new SelectOption(value, label);
```

From your class you are setting the label

```
SelectOption option =   new SelectOption(a.Id,a.Name);
```

Account name. later you are  replacing it with parentId

```
option.setLabel(a.ParentId);
```

In `visualforce` page `apex:selectOptions`tag handle the UI and display label to users.

You can check more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm)

Comment: thanx, but let me fix my answer,

Comment: @Eli you can add that in controller. Add values in `accounts` list or do you want to add them dynamically on UI?

Comment: thanx i found the solution. i'v added to the value a json string object contains all the data i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can add labels and values when you return a `List<SelectOption>` like below:

```
public String mySelectedOption { // Handle the selected value
  get;
  set {
    this.mySelectedOption = value;
  }
}

public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions() { // Get the selected value
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

  options.add(new SelectOption('Value', 'Label'));

  return options;
}
```

When you display this on a Visualforce Page...

```
<apex:selectList value="{!mySelectedOption}" size="1">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Something similar to following will get rendered on the page as HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="Value">Label</option>
</select>
```